# Replacing sub strings with regex in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following regex code in my powershell to identify URL's that I need to update:

```
'href[\s]?=[\s]?\"[^"]*(https:\/\/oursite.org\/[^"]*News and Articles[^"]*)+\"'
'href[\s]?=[\s]?\"[^"]*(https:\/\/oursite.org\/[^"]*en\/News-and-Articles[^"]*)+\"'
```

These are getting me the results I need to update, now I need to know how to replace the values "News and Articles" with "news-and-articles" and "en" with "news-and-articles".

I have some code that has a replacement url like so:

```
$newUrl = 'href="https://oursite.org/"' #replaced value
```

So the beginning result would be:

https://www.oursite.org/en/News-and-Articles/2017/11/article-name

to be replaced with

https://www.oursite.org/news-and-articles/2017/11/article-name

Here is the function that is going through all the articles and doing a replacement:

```
   function SearchItemForMatch
{
    param(
        [Data.Items.Item]$item
        )
    Write-Host "------------------------------------item: " $item.Name
    foreach($field in $item.Fields) {
        #Write-Host $field.Name
        if($field.Type -eq "Rich Text") {
            #Write-Host $field.Name
            if($field.Value -match $pattern) {
                ReplaceFieldValue -field $field -needle $pattern -replacement $newUrl
            }
            #if($field.Value -match $registrationPattern) {
            #   ReplaceFieldValue -field $field -needle $registrationPattern -replacement $newRegistrationUrl
            #}
            if($field.Value -match $noenpattern){
                ReplaceFieldValue -field $field -needle $noenpattern -replacment $newnoenpattern
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the replacement method:

```
 Function ReplaceFieldValue
    {
        param (
            [Data.Fields.Field]$field,
            [string]$needle,
            [string]$replacement
            )

        Write-Host $field.ID
        $replaceValue = $field.Value -replace $needle, $replacement
        $item = $field.Item
        $item.Editing.BeginEdit()
        $field.Value = $replaceValue
        $item.Editing.EndEdit()
        Publish-Item -item $item -PublishMode Smart

        $info = [PSCustomObject]@{
            "ID"=$item.ID
            "PageName"=$item.Name
            "TemplateName"=$item.TemplateName
            "FieldName"=$field.Name
            "Replacement"=$replacement
        }
        [void]$list.Add($info)
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?<=oursite\.org\/)(?:en\/)?News-and-Articles(?=\/)`

Replace with `news-and-articles`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iLLsL9/1)

Comment: Pardon me for my ignorance, how would I plug this into the code I have?  Sorry, I inherited this I have little to no experience with powershell

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm missing something, but it seems to me that all you really want to achieve is to get rid if the `/en` part and finally convert the whole url to lowercase.

Given your example url, this could be as easy as:

```
$url = 'https://www.oursite.org/en/News-and-Articles/2017/11/article-name'
$replaceValue = ($url -replace '/en/', '/').ToLower()
```

Result:

> https://www.oursite.org/news-and-articles/2017/11/article-name

If it involves more elaborate replacements, then please edit your question and give us more examples and desired output.